# Cannot implicitly convert type int to UnityEngine.GameObject[]"

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui, photon-pun

I am trying to get all of the GameObjects with the tag of `Player` but it comes up with the error *"Cannot implicitly convert type int to UnityEngine.GameObject[]"*. My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;

public class mymanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject[] amount;
    public GameObject winPanel;

    void Start()
    {
        winPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        amount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").Length;

        if(amount <= 1)
        {
            winPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            winPanel.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void OnClickJoinLobby()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Lobby");
    }
}
```

I wanted to count the amount of players and open a UI panel if there was a maximum of 1 player left.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if you include the full stack trace that appears with this error message. That will tell us on which specific line the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You gave the array of Gameobject `amount` an int value which is wrong, you need to give it Gameobjects, delete `.length`

```
amount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
```

And in the if condition check the length of it like this

```
if(amount.Length <= 1)
{
///
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").Length` returns the length of the array returned by `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")`.

If you only want how many player exists, you don't need the `GameObject[] amount`, just check the length:

```
int amount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player").Length;
if (amount <= 1) ...
```

Or if you want to do with them something, then

```
private GameObject[] _players;

...

_players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
int amount = _players.Length;

...
```